# changing wordpress page & tab title

Tags: php, wordpress, title

I have a little issue changing my pages and tab  of my wordpress website using PHP...

I would like this to be displayed :

```
when on the HOME PAGE :

MY WEBSITE NAME

and when on other pages :

MY WEBSITE NAME | PAGE NAME
```

using the bellow php code I get this :

```
when on the HOME PAGE :

MY WEBSITE NAME |

and when on other pages :

MY WEBSITE NAME | PAGE NAME
```

what I want is the "|" not to be displayed when on Home Page...
here is my code :

```
<title>
<?php if (is_home()){bloginfo('name');}
else
{ ?>
<?php bloginfo('name');} ?> | <?php echo strtoupper(wp_title('', false, '')); ?>
</title>
```

can anybody help me with this ?

thanks a lot,

Comment: I ususlly use **is_front_page()** instead of **is_home()**, try replacing it and see if it works. As a rule, **is_front_page()** is if your homepage is a static page and **is_home()** is for the default post feed.

Comment: @user2882154 See my answer also about ensuring you have set your "Settings->Reading->Front page displays" setting properly as well.

Comment: I think the problem is in my php code...

Comment: Does it work in reverse? i.e. <?php if(!is_front_page()){//whatever if not homepage}else{//whatever if is home page} ?>

Comment: Oh and you are missing a closed bracket for the else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to bet that `is_home()` is returning `false` on your "home page".

The [`is_front_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) function may actually be what you're looking for.  Ensure you have set your Settings->Reading->Front page displays setting properly as well.

The [`is_front_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) documentation also has a snippet (see Examples) that would probably work for you.

Have fun!

Comment: well that's not really the problem... the problem is that I get the "|" displayed both on my home page and on my inside pages...

Comment: @user2882154 Yes, that's correct. The fact that you get the "|" on both types of pages tells me that `is_home()` returns `false` in both cases (on your home page and on your subpages).  If you use the snippet given in the documentation (as a test) and make sure you have set your "Settings>Reading" properly, does it appear to work?

Answer (score 0):

Your current code has the end bracket of the else in the wrong place- after the `bloginfo('name');}`

```
<title>
<?php if (is_home()){bloginfo('name');}
else
{ ?>
<?php bloginfo('name');} ?> | <?php echo strtoupper(wp_title('', false, '')); ?>
</title>
```

It should be right at the end.

```
<title>
<?php if (is_home()){bloginfo('name');}
else
{ ?>
<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php echo strtoupper(wp_title('', false, '')); } ?>
</title>
```

Comment: While this is correct for the snippet he provided, wouldn't he be getting a hard syntax error (and the page wouldn't display at all)?

Comment: There is no syntax error. The code only says if homepage- show name, else, show name. What the OP wants is if homepage- show name, else, show name | something else. It's a typo, nothing more.

Comment: Are you sure? This is the correct answer for what you asked. A typo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to allow you to change the title tag for whatever page you want.  Replace what is already in your header  tag with this;

```
<title>
<?php if (is_home () ) { bloginfo(‘name’); }
elseif (is_category() ) { echo strip_tags(category_description()); }
elseif (is_single() ) { single_post_title().'|'.bloginfo(‘name’); }
elseif (is_page() ) { single_post_title().'|'.bloginfo(‘name’); }
else { wp_title(‘’,true); } ?>
</title>
```

This gives you the format you want.  It also allows you to set whatever title you want for each page type in wordpress.